# ASP.NET Web API user authorization

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have an ASP.NET Web API project API using JWT user authentication. I try using it in Postman. I got a user token, and when I try to send it with another request in header, I always get an error "401 Unauthorized".

I tried a lot of things, and always get the same error.

This is my code in `Startup.cs` file:

```
namespace Application
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public string SecretCode = SecretKeyGenerator.getSecretKey();

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                        {
                            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                    {
                                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                                        ValidateAudience = false,
                                        ValidateLifetime = false,
                                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                        // ValidIssuer = "moh", // Replace with your issuer
                                        // ValidAudience = "moh", // Replace with your audience
                                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("h#T5&d9vA@2$Gw1!zK6")) // Replace with your secret key
                                                                                                         // IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
 
                                    };
                    });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
 
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

This is user authentication controller:

```
[Route("api/auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
 
    public AuthController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public IActionResult login([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        string username = loginRequest.Username;
        string password = loginRequest.Password;

        // Validate user credentials (you can use your own logic here)
        if (IsValidUser(username, password))
        {
            var token = GenerateJwtToken(username);
            return Ok(new { token });
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }

    private bool IsValidUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (username == "moh")
        {
            if (password == "1111")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private string GenerateJwtToken(string username)
    {
        var claims = new[]
                     {
                         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
                         // Add more claims as needed
                     };

        SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("h#T5&d9vA@2$Gw1!zK6"));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
       // var expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_config["Jwt:ExpireMinutes"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        _config["Jwt:Audience"],
                        claims,
                        // expires: expires,
                        signingCredentials: creds);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

This is a another API controller to test user token:

```
namespace Applcation.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Info")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController1 : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("info")]
        public string Info([FromBody] strTest test)
        {
            return test.test;
        }
    }
}
```

In Postman, I get a token and I set it in second request like so:

[image]

I hope your help and thank you so much